# Angular 2 Module has no exported member

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I am again, hoping to find a quick solution to this:

[Link <- Click on this link to see the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2tab.png)

```
//main.ts
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './home.main';
import {InputComponent} from './home.controller';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';


bootstrap(InputComponent);
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

This is my main.ts file where I import the AppComponent from home main, now the home.main looks like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

    @Component({
    selector:'home',
    templateUrl:'/index/index.ejs'
    })

    export class InputComponent {
      name = 'test';
     }
```

However, when I run this, I get: `error TS2305: Module '"controllers/home/home.main"' has no exported member 'AppComponent'. ( Same goes for home.controller ).`

Thank you,
Alex S.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have something like that in your home.main module:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir :) I've put AppComponent in home controller and InputController in home.main ...

Answer (score 5):

If you see this error in any @angular modules like **router**, **core**, then make sure it is because of the version mismatch of the libraries. Generally all your @angular modules should be of the same version except router.

for Ex:

```js
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.0" <= Version mismatch***
```

the following combination throws following error

> has no exported member

I changed the router version to

> "@angular/router": "^3.0.0"

The error is resolved.

So, until everything is stable stick with your working combination.

Comment: But how to do that?

Comment: Version mismatch seems highly likely. I had a similar issue where @angular/core, @angular/forms, @angular/http, @angular/platform-browser-dynamic and other packages were all version `^4.2.4` but @angular/platform-browser had been updated to `^5.0.0`, which resulted in a Module has no exported member StaticProvider error. Changing the version back to 4.2.4 made the problem disappear. And reading about the [angular5 changes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) from `Provider[]` to `StaticProvider[]` backs that up as an proper fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue even when I had correctly exported the class on my other file. Rebooting my machine fixed it.